# Jquery conflicts not allowing to trigger events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I am creating a jQuery plug-in for web applications. My plug-in captures page events and replay back all events which i captured. Normally web applications use jQuery frameworks and i am also using one version, so I used `noConflict` to overcome conflict problems.

My plug-in will integrated with any web application. so i cant change anything in web application. All changes should be in done in plug-in itself.

My Plug-in Code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.ui.dialog.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var JqNoConflict = $.noConflict(true);  
</script>
<script src="captureall.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Web Application Code

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This the files I am using to create my plug in.

I can capture all the events from web page. When i populate back i am using trigger function to trigger all events which i captured. I am facing problem of,

```
JqNoConflict("DIV").eq(30).trigger('click');
```

it is not working, instead of

```
$("DIV").eq(30).trigger('click');
```

this code is working.

NOTE : i placed my plugin code all over the place in page. top, bottom, middle. nothing works.(it captures,not triggering)

I am facing major problems, when i captures dialog and calendar events.

I need a solution for above problem,

1. I need to know that which jQuery framework gets called when events happened.may be that will help to find which jQuery framework gets called
2. I need to know that, is it possible to call a trigger event `$().trigger();` from  `JqNoConflict() .trigger();`
3. is there anyway to write a code to capture a events and trigger back from myself defined `JqNoConflict` jQuery frameworks?

Comment: Don't use more than one version of jQuery.... problem solved.

Comment: Rory, web application will use only one. My plugin also use one jquery.  thats make this problem.

Comment: @chandramohan You're approaching it backwards. You tell the web application developer that they need jQuery 1.9.1+ for your plug-in, and then they use it. If they decide they need to also have another version of jQuery then let *them* worry about any conflicts.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes correct. but im developing this plug in for few web applications,which is already developed and working fine in live. then how i can restrict them to use. if i didn't care, may be integrated application can have weird behaviors or having crash problems.

Comment: The problem is that you're using `.noConflict()` but you actually want conflict, e.g., the ability for your plugin to affect the jQuery-based behavior of the host page. Use their jQuery.